# Unable to reject a suggested edit due to missing HTML attribute

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

When trying to reject a suggested edit with the custom/harmful reason that requires an explanation, I am unable to cause the 'reject' button to be clickable, despite entering more than 20 characters.

While the question I encountered this on has the edit rejected now, this is the error I got in the console on full.en.js:7:6029

[image]

Testing other posts from the review queue encounters the same issue. I'm on Firefox 90.0.2 on Windows.

Machavity spoke with Adam Lear and suggested in chat that it might be a CDN issue:

> I'm having a very similar issue on the mod console and Adam Lear wasn't able to reproduce. But it's that same type of problem: no elements are being returned.
>
> He thinks the CDN might be out of sync but he's not sure. But I get my errors on FF90 and Edge 92 (which I never use so I could dump all cache)
>
> I also get that error when looking at a Teams post

Rejecting via other options that don't require a custom reason works just fine.

Edit: Currently suspecting the Fastly CDN server in Atlanta that is my first hop to stackoverflow.com. It is serving me (and Machavity, too) a file from July 22nd. Anyone who has a different first hop based on geography would not be able to reproduce.

Comment: Hm, no repro on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on Windows, interesting. Any suggested edit in particular to test on just in case?

Comment: @OlegValter When I asked in chat, others could see the button as active on the very one I was having issues with. However, this one currently has a pending edit and I also can't click the button for it after typing in a custom reject reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68522865/css-drop-down-menu-not-working-when-i-hover-over-link

Comment: I tried the one you just linked in firefox, chrome, and edge on Windows. I cannot reproduce this bug. It's really weird. Could it be a userscript or extension? I tried disabling all of mine and still no repro.

Comment: @10Rep I disabled all extensions and had the same issue. The fact that Machavity had the same error but Adam (a developer) did not indicates it's a highly intermittent issue (which, understandably, might make it significantly harder to track down and fix)... of course if it is DNS or a CDN issue, it could resolve itself given enough time. I know the DBAs have been having a... fun time... the last week.

Comment: works fine here, and I've never had a review-related extension. (you fooled me into performing a review task)

Comment: @KevinB FWIW, I only have a user-style add-on for review, and it only applies to [making the close vote review queue better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361393/253521).

Comment: @TylerH thank you. Still can't reproduce, though, how weird. Add a mobile Chrome to the roster. It may indeed be something that resolves itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like (based on discussions and some troubleshooting with Adam Lear) that some CDN nodes got locked into an older version of a JS file from last week. He forced a refresh and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm now after Ctrl+F5ing this morning that I no longer have the issue. [meta-tag:status-resolved].

Comment: Well I learned something from this ordeal. If you setup CDN's, always keep in the back of your head that this can happen and setup some way to check that all CDNs are synced.